# Cross join in data.table within a function

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to create a cross join `data.table` within a function. Say, we've got a vector `vals <- c("yes", "no")`. Now this one works: `CJ(vals, vals)`. However, depending on the function input, I might need to create e.g. `CJ(vals, vals, vals, vals)` instead. Something like

```
vals <- c("yes", "no")
n <- 4
CJ(rep(vals, n))
```

obviously wouldn't work. How can I specify the vectors for cross-joining in a flexible manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `...` which are used to refer to arguments passed down from a calling function...?

```
require( data.table )
f <- function( ... ){
    CJ(...)
}

f( c(1:2) , c(3:4) )
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  3
#2:  1  4
#3:  2  3
#4:  2  4
```

---

**Edit:** How about this?

```
do.call(CJ, replicate(n, vals, simplify=FALSE))

#      V1  V2  V3  V4
#  1:  no  no  no  no
#  2:  no  no  no yes
#  3:  no  no yes  no
#  4:  no  no yes yes
#  5:  no yes  no  no
#  6:  no yes  no yes
#  7:  no yes yes  no
#  8:  no yes yes yes
#  9: yes  no  no  no
# 10: yes  no  no yes
# 11: yes  no yes  no
# 12: yes  no yes yes
# 13: yes yes  no  no
# 14: yes yes  no yes
# 15: yes yes yes  no
# 16: yes yes yes yes
```

Comment: But again, in this case I'd need to explicitly write `f(vals, vals)` to create the `data.table` with two columns, and `f(vals, vals, vals, vals)` to create one with four columns. However, I'd like just to specify the number of repeats (e.g. `n = 2` or `n = 4`) rather than explicitly writing down the vector name that many times.

Comment: Great, thanks, the edit does exactly what I want! I've been playing around with `do.call` but I didn't think of using `replicate`.

Comment: @AnjaM I think **@Arun** has answered your question superbly with the edit. Arguably he should have left that as his own answer and earned the rep, praise and admiration of fellow useRs himself, but I'm not complaining.